# Amazon EC2 - Will EBS be charged when using spots?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am new to Amazon EC2. If you use a spot and, let say an amazon AMI like the Windows 2008 one. Will you have to pay for the (temporaly) 30GB which comes with the amazon AMI?

All I found so far is the calculator and prizes for EBS for a month. But my EBS gets deleted when i terminate my spot, so I think its cheaper, is it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you will be charged for the EBS space when you start a spot instance.

It's not the most intuitive thing in the world, but give the [AWS Calculator](http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html) a shot to check out what your prices would be.

Oh, and just as an FYI: It's really not a good idea to run something like a web server as a spot instance. They are designed for things that can easily be stopped without affecting operations, because if the price shoots up for an hour for whatever reason, your instance will be terminated.